# Raspbian 10 boot on Pi3 but not boot on pi4

Tags: boot, pi-4, raspbian-buster

I have a copy of a working raspbian 10 SD card. When I clone it, clone SD card didnt boot on pi4 giving error:

```
print_req_error i/o error dev mmcblk0 sector 0 
buffer io error on dev mmcblk0, logical 0, async page read
```

I plugged same SD card to pi3 model b+ and it booted normally.

What is the reason of it? How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

I dont know how but I used another SD card and it works.